# retrieving image from database using php

Tags: php, file-upload, mysqli

```
<?php
$file= $_FILES["file"]["name"];//file selected in form 
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";


      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "c:/EasyPHP-12.1/www/new website/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "c:/EasyPHP-12.1/www/new website/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      if(($_FILES['file']['size'] >0))
        {echo 'imagetrue';$con=mysql_connect('localhost','abc','YES') or die ("con");;
                    $db=mysql_select_db("website",$con) or die ("db");
                    $query=mysql_query("insert into website.picture (imagew) values ('$file')") or die('query'); //storing in db}
      //echo $_FILES['file']['error'] ;

      $query2= mysql_query("select * from website.picture");
$res=mysql_fetch_array($query2);
foreach($res as $row){ 
$str = "c:/EasyPHP-12.1/www/new website/upload/ ".$row['imagew'];
echo '<img src="'.$str.'" alt="no">' ;}

?>
```

i am using this script to store image and then displaying it on webpage but it is not working it only displays empty thumbnails...

Comment: Have you confirmed the files are being written into that directory?

Comment: yes the images are copied in the upload folder after storing its name in database

Comment: Have you tried confirming that the URL of the image you're using in the <img> tag works by copying it and pasting it into the browser? I assume you're running this site on the same machine you're testing on, since it's a local path.

Comment: yes i have tested and its not working

Comment: change this line (echo '<img src=..) to echo file_exists($str) ? '<img src="'.$str.'" alt="no">': 'not found';

Comment: I'd play with the URL until it does work, that should show what's gone wrong. For example, try replacing that space with a "%20" and see if that helps, things like that. You've already narrowed it down pretty well, we know the problem is that the URL is wrong somehow, just have to poke at it until it works.

Comment: @AkamOmer : following error was there after replacing code 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'imagew' in C:\EasyPHP-12.1\www\upload_file.php on line 34
not found

Comment: @Mike: error after substituting %20 

Warning: Illegal string offset 'imagew' in C:\EasyPHP-12.1\www\upload_file.php on line 34
not found

Comment: not found! then the image is not there, see @Andy solution first, you can simply copy address of the images folder in the address bar and check what is the difference

Comment: @AkamOmer: image is present in the upload folder and name is also there in database

Comment: use this: while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
  $str = "c:/EasyPHP-12.1/www/new website/upload/ ".$row['imagew'];
  echo '<img src="'.$str.'" alt="no">' ;
} and delete $res=mysql_fetch_array($query2);

Comment: @AkamOmer: replaced the code but result is:  empty thumbnails

Comment: could you echo $str; and see what is there?

Comment: $str displays the path of every image

Answer (score 1):

I'd be very suspect about using absolute paths like c:/EasyPHP-12.1/www/new website/upload/

I'f you're then accessing the page from `http://127.0.0.1/new-website` (which I presume you are - or something similar) then having windows system pathnames could be a problem - do browsers even read the local filesystem like that ?

Also, it makes it very un-portable for when you move it to another server.

I'd suggest $str = 'upload/'.$row['imagew'];  So it's relative to the document hosted in (I presume) `127.0.0.1/new website/image-viewer.php` (or whatever you called it)

Comment: updated the path but still error :   Warning: Illegal string offset 'imagew' in C:\EasyPHP-12.1\www\upload_file.php on line 34
not found

Comment: the absolute path "upload/" $_FILES["file"]["name"] is not working images are not copied in the upload folder

Comment: What? You have said several times that the images are copied in the upload folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of move_uploaded_file() - if it's false then it has failed.  If that's failing try using the relative path :

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);`

This again presumes your script is sitting in `127.0.0.1/new-website`

EDIT - NOTE :::  Is your form using enctype="multipart/form-data"  ?    If it's not then the images never get to the server !